# Local extrema in special directions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization

I am looking for the extrema of a function $G(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$ subject to the constraint $y_1 = y_4 + y_2y_3.$ We know that $G$ is defined if $(y_2,y_3,y_4)$ is in the cylinder $\mathbb{D} \times \mathbb{R},$ where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk of the plane. At a stationary point $(y^*,\lambda^*)$ of the usual Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(y, \lambda),$ the Hessian is 
 $$  \nabla_{yy} \mathcal{L}(y^*,\lambda^*) = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 &-2({y_4^*}^2+1)  & 2y_4^* & 0 \\ 0& 2y_4^* & -2{y_4^*}^2 &0 \\ -2&0&0&0   \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, set $w^* = [w_1,w_2,w_3,w_1] \in \mathbb{R}^4,$ which is in the tangent plane of the constraint. Then
 $$  w^* \nabla_{yy} \mathcal{L}(y^*,\lambda^*) w < 0$$
if $y_4^* \neq 0 $ and $ w_2,w_3 \neq 0.$

Here is the messy thing for me:
Now consider the $y_4^*$-section of the cylinder  $\mathbb{D} \times \mathbb{R};$ that is, the set of $(y_2,y_3,y_4^*)$-s. The previous inequality of the Hessian means that the restriction of $G$ onto the set $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4^*)$ (subject to the constraint above) has strict local maximum at $y^*$? Any hint is welcomed.

Comment: 1) is $w_4$ really equal $w_1$? 2) for the sufficient condition, you may assume $w\ne 0$, however not more. That is, $w_2,w_3\ne 0$ need follow from the fact that $w$ is tangent.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to write that $y^* = (y_4^*,0,0,y_4^*).$ For 1), I think 'yes' since    $(\nabla c)(y^*) = (1,0,0,-1)$ for the constraint function $c(y) = y_1 - y_2y_3 - y_4.$ (I calculated the Lagrangian and the Hessian according to this function.)
   Hence the tangent plane is the set of vectors $[w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4].$ Except for the direction $[w_1,0,0,w_1],$ the Hessian is negative.

Comment: $w$ is tangent to the surface if and only if $w_1 = w_4$. This includes $w=(1, 0, 0, 1)$. Notice that you can analyze the restricted problem by simply adding the constraint $y_4 = y_4^*$.

Comment: oh, really... with this extra condition the vectors $(0,w_2,w_3,0)$ form the tangent space of the constraints... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even restricted, $y^*$ need not be a local maximum. Necessary would be
$$ w^* \nabla_{yy} \mathcal L(y^*, \lambda^*) w \le 0 $$
for all $w^* = (w_1, w_2, w_3, 0)$ in the tangent space, that is
$$ w_1 - y_3^*w_2 - y_2^* w_3 = 0. $$
Strictly less for sufficient condition. Since the (1,1) element of the hessian is $1$, it depends on $y_2^*$ and $y_3^*$.

Comment: I corrected the question... now it has more sense.